# Problem using the Newline Character in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to write a function which will return a rectangle of *'s. It keeps throwing up an error whenever I try to use \n. I assume i'm using it incorrectly but don't know how - can anyone help?

```
function makeRectangle(m, n) {
    return '*'.repeat(m) \n.repeat(n);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must concat `\n` using `+` operator before next repeat

```js
function makeRectangle(m, n) {
  return ("*".repeat(m) + "\n").repeat(n)
}

console.log(makeRectangle(3, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

The newline needs to be enclosed as a string:

```
function makeRectangle(m, n) {
    return ('*'.repeat(m) + '\n').repeat(n);
}
```

or just for fun, a string literal version, to eliminate the '\n' entirely.

```
function makeRectangle(m, n) {
    return `${`${'*'.repeat(m)}
`.repeat(n)}`;
}

console.log(makeRectangle(5, 6))
```